# How to simulate on `onChange` event that updates the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I'm writing an application in React and I'm unit testing this with Jest and Enzyme.

I have a very simple component that represents an input field, which contains the following code:

```
// 'Container' component definition.
class Container extends React.Component<containerProps, containerState> {
  static defaultProps = { };
  state = {
    hasValue: false
  };

  constructor(props: containerProps) {
    super(props);

    // Bind all the event handlers for the component.
    (this: any).onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event: MouseEvent) : void {
    this.setState(
      {
        hasValue: (event.target: window.HTMLInputElement).value !== ''
      }
    );

    // Prevent a default browser event from happening.
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  createComponentProps(): componentProps {
    return {
      cssClass: this.createComponentCssClass()
    };
  }

  // Create the CSS class to pass to the component.
  createComponentCssClass(): string {
    let className = '';

    if (this.state.hasValue) { className = className !== '' ? className + 'value' : 'value'; }
    if (this.props.errorMessage && this.props.errorMessage !== '') {
      className = className !== '' ? className + ' error' : 'error';
    }

    // Return the CSS class to apply to the component.
    return className;
  }

  // Renders the 'Container' component.
  render(): React$Element<any> {
    return (
      <Component {...this.createComponentProps()} />
    );
  }
}
```

So, it's a fairly simple component.
Now, when the contents of the input field are changed, a state change occurs which forces a different CSS class to be applied to the component.

I can confirm that this is working since it's working in the browser as intended.

Now, I'm writing a unit test to verify that the className `value` is passed to the component using the following code:

```
it('Passes down the \'cssClass\' property to the \'Input Field\' Component.', () => {
  // Act.
  const wrapper = mount(
    <InputFieldContainer primaryThemeColor="TEAL" accentThemeColor="PINK" useAccentColor={true} />
  );
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'value' }});
  wrapper.update();

  // Assert.
  expect(wrapper.find(InputFieldComponent).props().cssClass).toEqual('value');
});
```

Thus, I'm rendering the component, I simulate a change event, and I check the CSS class property of the component, however, it's an empty string. It seems it didn't update regarding the state change (but only in unit tests).

Reading the state in Jest, using `console.log(wrapper.state())` gives me a JSON object saying `hasValue: true`, so the state is updated, but even after calling `wrapper.update()`, the CSS class does not seem to be passed.

What am I missing here?

Kind regards

Comment: why ```InputFieldComponent``` when u have ```InputFieldContainer ``` above?

Comment: I'm using a Container component to render the Actual component, so the container component changes the state and based on the state change, the component is rendered again.

Comment: wont this be a better option for getting the class? http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html#hasclassclassname--boolean

Comment: That might be an option, but it won't work when I'm passing other properties, which are not a className. I'm trying to retrieve the properties of the actual component, not the container, with the following piece of code `wrapper.find(InputFieldComponent).props().cssClass` however, it's an empty string, like the state is never updated. But if I put a `console.log(props)` statement in my component, then there's a value assigned to `cssClass` which contains the correct value... [UPDATE]: Using `hasClass` as suggested doesn't work.

Comment: i see, btw is this a shallow render?

Comment: I've used to try it, but now I'm using `mount`, however, not any difference at all.

Comment: Hmm, If i change my expect method to the following; `expect(wrapper.find(InputFieldComponent).find('.value').length).toEqual(1);`, then everything is working, however, I don't understand why I can't use `props()`.

Comment: might be helpful https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.md#props--objectm which might mean that only these ```primaryThemeColor="TEAL" accentThemeColor="PINK" useAccentColor={true}``` can be returned by ```props()```

Comment: It seems that it's only related to shallow rendering, while I'm using `mount`.

Comment: have you tested it though? they did not provide the mount so i cant tell. try logging ```wrapper.find(InputFieldCOmponent).props()```

Comment: Ok, found a solution, the following `expect` statement works when using `mount`. `expect(wrapper.find(InputFieldComponent).props().cssClass).toEqual('value');`Since you point me in the right direction, I want to award you the points, but then you need to write an answer :-)

Comment: isnt that the same as before? rofl

Comment: Hmm, seems that I've added a DIV around the component in the container which causes it to work. Any idea on how that's possible? Using `shallow` is not an option.

Comment: Seems that it's related to this particular issue: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1153

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Enzyme (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1153).

After updating the wrapper and your component should be in sync.